# how to pass data from one window to another?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on C# wpf, and I am trying to create 'favorite' function on it.
There is one window called 'favorite' and it is where a user can save his data.
Another window is 'MainWindow' and I want to load the data here.

There are two buttons and two textbox in 'favorite'.
If I type words in each box, I hope they can be saved if I click star1button.
And if I type another words in each box, I hope they would be saved if I click star2button. 
So I hope each data will be stored separately, without being overlapped.

And then, if I press button1 on 'mainwindow', I hope those words of star1button would show up in textboxes of mainwindow. 
And if I press button2 on mainwindow, I hope words of star2button would show up in textboxes of mainwindow.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is a broad topic to discuss if you want to do it right. I'd recommend a read about the MVVM pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can place an attribute in your App.xaml.cs which should be accessible from both

```
namespace MyApp
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public string myValue;

        // the rest of your App.xaml.cs code 
    }
}
```

Then in your MainWindow and other window put this code

```
    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (Application.Current as MyApp.App).myValue;
        }
        set
        {
            (Application.Current as MyApp.App).myValue= value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static class to pass values between windows.

```cs
public static class CurrentParameters
{
    public static string mySharedValue { get; set; }
}
```